# Proper way of De-allocating 2D dynamic array of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm having difficulty de-allocating a 2D array of pointers to class objects. I've gotten the gist that if I use new, I need to call delete; and if I use new[] I need to call delete[]. I think where I'm really having the disconnect is the sequence in which I call delete or delete[].

Unfortunately, this is a class assignment. Using STL containers like std:: gets an auto 0 for the assignment.

So I have the following array of 1000 rows and 2 columns that I allocate on the heap:

```
Node*** arr_ptr = new Node**[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    arr_ptr[i] = new Node*[2];
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        arr_ptr[i][j] = new Node();
    }
}
```

and the array works fine for what I need it for, regarding this assignment. I can store stuff via the object pointers, no issues. Once I get to de-allocation, I'm getting hit with segfaults. I'm under the impression, that de-allocation is like allocation; only in reverse. When I allocated all this memory, I made an outer array; a sub-array, and then I store a bunch of pointers to Node objects. So I assumed that I would go in the reverse order and delete all the stored pointers in the array, delete the sub-array, and then delete the outer array. Yet, going about it in that order gives me the segfault.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        // delete stored pointers
        delete arr_ptr[i][j];
    }
    // delete sub array
    delete[] arr_ptr[i];
}
// delete outer array
delete[] arr_ptr;

// point arr_ptr back to NULL
arr_ptr = NULL;
```

I did try changing the call to delete on the stored pointers in the nested for-loop from 'delete' to 'delete[]', I didn't think that would work but it still gives a segfault. I think that was more humoring myself more than anything.

I did look at the part of the program that throws the segfault though in GDB. On the very first iteration of the nested for-loop `delete arr_ptr[i][j];` is what gives the segfault.

Not sure if I'm completely off-base with this or if I even have the right idea when it comes to dynamic memory management in c++, but any constructive feed-back or nudges in the right direction are welcome.

[EDIT]: John mentioned that somewhere else in my code things are going awry. And I think I found it. I dumped the contents of the file I loaded into the array and it wasn't exactly what I expected. All of node pointers in the array are populated with data except for the first two positions in the arr_ptr, at indices [0][0], and [0][1].

So the code in question (I have a feeling I'm about to get lit up by everyone) that creates the array, and loads the lines of the file into said array looks like this:

```
void Language::initialize()
{

    // prompt user for file
    cout << "Name of language file to read in: ";
    cin >> file_name;


    // open file for reading
    file.open(file_name.c_str());

    // read in language and line count
    string language = "";
    file >> language;
    file >> count;

    // create dynamic array with 1000 rows and 2 columns
    arr_ptr = new Node **[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        arr_ptr[i] = new Node*[2];

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            arr_ptr[i][j] = new Node();
        }
    }

    // iterate over file, reading data into arr_ptr[i][j]
    // Column 0 : German - Column 1 : English
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // stores the ith line of file as string
        string line_entry;

        // read one line from the file
        getline(file, line_entry);

        // tokenize line input
        string german = this->split(line_entry, "German");
        string english = this->split(line_entry, "English");

        // store tokens into corresponding array locations
        arr_ptr[i][0]->data = german;
        arr_ptr[i][0]->index = i;
        arr_ptr[i][1]->data = english;
        arr_ptr[i][1]->index = i;
    }

    // notify user file was successfully processed 
    cout << "File successfully processed!" << endl;

    // close file
    file.close();
}
```

Code for the split function that I wrote:

```
string Language::split(string s1, string s2)
{
    // token storing substring
    string token = "";

    // store delimited line of text
    string line = s1;

    // store delimiter used in file
    string delim = ",";

    // determines which substring function generates
    // "German" : substring from s.at(0) to ',' delimiter 
    // "English" : substring from ',' delimiter to end of string
    string lang = s2;

    if (lang == "German")
    {
        // get position of delimiter in line
        int pos = line.find(delim);

        // grab substring from beginning to delimiter
        token = line.substr(0, pos);

        return token;
    }

    if (lang == "English")
    {
        // get position of delimiter in line
        int pos = line.find(delim);

        // grab substring from delimiter to end of string
        token = line.substr(pos + 1);

        return token;
    }

    // returns empty token if no lang is specified
    return token;
}
```

So, now I'm gonna go back and try maybe reading the file in differently so I don't have blank entries at indices [0][0], and [0][1] in my 2D array. Though I am confused as to why that's occurring in the first place. I was under the impression that if I open a file for reading, and use stream extraction to read the first 2 words of the first line. Using getline in a loop should just read the lines as normal. But for some reason the first line read in, is blank.

Comment: What's wrong with your exposed code? It appears correct to me. It works on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17323c7ff59e9432). You mentioned the essence _if I use new, I need to call delete; and if I use new[] I need to call delete[]._ If you get a segmentation fault, it's probably caused by something else. Maybe, you change pointers in any of the arrays in the code which is not exposed...

Comment: The code you posted is correct. The reason for your crash is somewhere else in your code. It's a common mistake to think that the code where the crash happens is the cause of the crash but C++ is not so simple. A crash when deleting allocated memory is often caused by a corrupted heap, but that is only one possibility. Deleting the same memory twice is another possibility. Basically there is not enough information here to know what is the cause of your bug, only that it is not the code you have posted.

Comment: >>  Using STL containers like std:: gets an auto 0 ... Could teacher just stop freaking do this...

Comment: If you are not allowed to use standard-library *containers*, perhaps you are allowed to use `std::unique_ptr`. If so, **use it**! Otherwise, why don't you create a flat array of objects instead of a jagged array of pointers? `Node* arr = new Node[1000*2];`